# MediatR pipeline that saves a generic DbContext after each command

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core, mediatr

I am trying to create a MediatR pipeline which calls the SaveChangesAsync on my DbContext after each command. I am trying to make this work in a generic way, so that I can add the pipeline with DI, and it will work for all my commands. By default, I want to save it, but I want to have the option in my command to set a boolean, and if it is set to false, I do not want to call the SaveChangesAsync on my DbContext. I have basically come to a working solution, but in my DI registration, I have to specify which DbContext I am using, which I want to prevent.

I have written the following code:
SaveCommandBehavior:

```
public class SaveCommandBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> _requestHandler;

    public SaveCommandBehavior(IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> requestHandler)
    {
        _requestHandler = requestHandler;
    }
    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        var response = await next();

        var isDbCommandHandler = IsAssignableToGenericType(_requestHandler.GetType(), typeof(DbCommandHandler<>));


        if (isDbCommandHandler &&
            _requestHandler is DbCommandHandler<MyDbContext> commandHandler &&
            request is DbCommand { SaveChanges: true } or DbCommand<TResponse> { SaveChanges: true })
        {
                await commandHandler.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        return response;
    }

    public static bool IsAssignableToGenericType(Type givenType, Type genericType)
    {
        var interfaceTypes = givenType.GetInterfaces();

        foreach (var it in interfaceTypes)
        {
            if (it.IsGenericType && it.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType)
                return true;
        }

        if (givenType.IsGenericType && givenType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType)
            return true;

        Type baseType = givenType.BaseType;
        if (baseType == null) return false;

        return IsAssignableToGenericType(baseType, genericType);
    }
}
```

Registration:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddSaveCommandPipelineLocal(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(SaveCommandBehavior<,>));
    }
```

Abstract classes that I use in my commands:

```
 public abstract class DbCommand: ICommand 
    {
        public bool SaveChanges { get; set; } = true;
    }
    public abstract class DbCommand<TResponse> : ICommand<TResponse>
    {
        public bool SaveChanges { get; set; } = true;
    }

    public abstract class DbCommandHandler<TDbContext> where TDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public TDbContext DbContext;

        protected DbCommandHandler(TDbContext dbContext)
        {
            DbContext = dbContext;
        }
    }
```

Example command and handler:

```
public sealed class MyCommand: DbCommand
{
    public Guid Parameter1  { get; set; }
}

public class MyCommandHandler: DbCommandHandler<MyDbContext>, ICommandHandler<MyCommand>
{


    public MyCommandHandler(MyDbContext dbContext)
        : base(dbContext)
    {
      
    }
    public async Task<Unit> Handle(MyCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Command logic making changes to EF, without calling save.
    }
}
```

While this code would work, I have to use
_requestHandler is DbCommandHandler commandHandler
which I do not want: I already know at that point that I am dealing with a _requestHandler which should have a DbContext of base type 'DbContext', which should be enough information to call 'SaveChangesAsync' on it. However, I can not figure out how to get that type, without having to specify which DbContext I am dealing with.
I am able to figure out whether or not it is a valid type with a DbContext of any type, using the isDbCommandHandler variable, but I can then not utilise that to cast this to a usable variable of which I can use the DbContext.

I feel like I am overlooking something simple. I feel like I should add a parameter TContext to SaveCommandBehavior where TContext : DbContext, so I can use that in the cast, but then I have an extra generic parameter in my SaveCommandBehavior which would make my DI fail, since the PipelineBehavior only takes 2 parameters

Answer (score 0):

A proposed alternative more than a direct answer.

What if you don't get the DbContext form the handler, but you inject it in the pipeline?

You can still check for the abstract class / interface for  the bool just to know if you need to save, but you can get rid of the dependency between the handler and the dbcontext.

```cs
public class SaveCommandBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> _requestHandler;
    private readonly MyDbContext _myDbContext;

    public SaveCommandBehavior(
MyDbContext myDbContext,
IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> requestHandler)
    {
        _requestHandler = requestHandler;
    }
    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        var response = await next();

        var isDbCommandHandler = IsAssignableToGenericType(_requestHandler.GetType(), typeof(DbCommandHandler<>));


        if (isDbCommandHandler &&
            request is DbCommand { SaveChanges: true } or DbCommand<TResponse> { SaveChanges: true })
        {
                await _myDbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        return response;
    }
...
}
```

The only problem that I see with this is that right now you are using only one dbcontext which is most likely something is the case for most projects.

In case you want to use multiple DBcontexts you would have to inject a factory instead of MyDbContext.

That factory would have to get the DbContext With the service provider like

```
serviceProvider.GetRequierdService<MyDbContext>();
```

```
interface IDbContextFactory{
DbContext GetDBContextForType(Type type);
}

class DbContextFactory : IDBContextFactory{

DbContext GetDBContextForType(Type type){
//Some custom logic here
}

}
```

Comment: I guess something like this should work, I'm assuming that by default a DbContext is added to the DI container as scoped, which would give me the same context. While I currently indeed have 1 DbContext, I want to be able to support multiple. I wanted to extract the logic which adds the save pipeline and make it generic, so I could put it in a Nuget package to use in multiple projects. I feel like I'm still leaning more towards getting it from the handler. If for some reason it would not be possible to get it from the handler and make it work for all DbContexts, I'll might go this route.